# How to transpose a list to a square matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transpose a list of items  into a square matrix format using python . 
I tried pivot_table in pandas but it didn't work.

Here is my code  , the input being a two column csv file

```
with open(path_to_file,"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ',')
    data = list(reader)
    row_count=len(data)
    print(row_count - 1)


df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)


groups = df.groupby(['transmitter chan', 'receiver chan'])
max_for_AS = defaultdict(int)
df = df.assign(ID = [0 + i for i in xrange(len(df))])

print(df)

for g in groups:
    transmitter, count = g[0][0], len(g[1])
    max_for_AS[ transmitter ] = max( max_for_AS[transmitter], count )

for g in groups:
    transmitter, receiver, count = g[0][0], g[0][1], len(g[1])
    if count == max_for_AS[ transmitter ]:
    dataFinal = "{} , {} , {}".format(transmitter, receiver, count )
        print( dataFinal )
```

Data:

```
  V1 V2  count
0  A  R      1
1  Z  T      4
2  E  B      9
3  R  O      8
4  T  M      7
5  Y  K      5
6  B  I      6
7  T  Z      2
8  A  O      7
9  Y  B      8
```

Comment: Please post your data, not a picture of your data.  Also, please what code you have attempted so far.

Comment: are these numpy arrays? pandas dataframe? can you post the code you tried somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
```

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='V1',columns='V2',values='count').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

---

```
df1 = df.set_index(['V1','V2'])['count'].unstack(fill_value=0)
```

But if duplicates in `V1` and `V2` need aggregate them:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='V1',columns='V2',values='count', fill_value=0)
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['V1','V2'])['count'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

```
#for change ordering add reindex
df1 = df1.reindex(index=df.V1.unique(), columns=df.V2.unique())
print (df1)
V2  R  T  B  O  M  K  I  Z
V1                        
A   1  0  0  7  0  0  0  0
Z   0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
E   0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0
R   0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0
T   0  0  0  0  7  0  0  2
Y   0  0  8  0  0  5  0  0
B   0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0
```

Comment: Small advice - [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear what you are trying to achieve, I'll approach this answer with an assumption.

I assume that you have a `pandas dataframe`. If that's true, to get the transpose of it using `numpy`, you might have to,

1. Convert the `dataframe`(df) to a `numpy ndarray` like this: `df=df.values`
2. Find the transpose using `numpy.transpose` on the result of step 1

Edit:

Better way. You can also do `df.transpose()`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it right now.

Comment: Try  `df.transpose`